# Edge: In-Process native extension and Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync

Tags: c#, uwp, launcher, ui-thread, microsoft-edge-extension

I have developed an edge browser extension (native messaging) using the in-process mechanism as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/convert-app-service-in-process) (through an activation of `OnBackgroundActivated`). Within `OnBackgroundActivated`, or to be more specific in `OnAppServiceRequestReceived` of the established app service connection, I am attempting to call `Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(IStorageFile)`. This doesn't appear to happen on the UI-Thread (although it does work in debug mode with a debugger attached).

The problem that I am facing is, that the application is headless, and therefore there is no `CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher`, nor could I retrieve the dispatcher from `Window.Current`.

How do I force `LaunchFileAsync` to be executed on the UI-Thread even in release mode or without a debugger attached ?

I do know that I can simply do the following:

```
  await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, (async () =>
  {
    bool success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(shortcut);
    await args.Request.SendResponseAsync(new ValueSet {
      { "message", "Launched File: " + success.ToString() }
    });
  }));
```

But my problem is getting hold of the `Dispatcher` reference within the Application-Class and in the context of `OnAppServiceRequestReceived`.

How can this be achieved? Is it even possible or do I need a full-trust Win32 desktop bridge?

Even using

```
CoreDispatcher dispatcher = Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.Dispatcher;
```

does not work without a Debugger attached. I am curious as to whether calling LaunchFileAsync is possible at all in a head-less UWP app, without a Win32 Desktop Bridge.

Comment: For " application is headless" here, did you mean the app running on windows IOT? If in that case, where is the edge run on?

Comment: By headless I mean the application has no foreground window. It's only purpose is to launch the default application for a file. The application is intended to run on a normal Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct - you will need to build a full-trust Win32 Desktop Bridge. The Dispatcher is not exposed inside the `OnAppServiceRequestReceived` context. So you wont be able to launch whatever you intend.